# Links at the end, like in a research paper

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

In the Stack Overflow question [Improving "randomness" when extending the range of rand()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23523852/improving-randomness-when-extending-the-range-of-rand) the links are at the end, like in a research paper, instead of in the text, like hyperlinks are most often used on the web. This is ugly, bad and horrible, right?

Comment: Meh. Like, really... Meh. I find it hard to get worked up about this either way. :)

Comment: I dislike it. It requires me to stop reading, scroll to the bottom to find the links, open them and scroll back to the top to continue reading.

Comment: Markdown already supports that syntax *within the post* to stick all the links at the bottom.  Actually *displaying* the links like that, though, is madness.  This isn't some research paper, this is a post on a *hypertext-based* Q&A site.  Links belong inline.

Comment: Of all the non-issues, this is probably the nonnest. It's rather rare to see it done like this in the first place, serves barely any functional difference and is just a matter of preference by the OP. Let posts keep some identity, this is not something I would deter people over.

Comment: While I encouraged the person I originally debated to open this up on meta, OP has hardly made an attempt to be objective over the topic.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They're not linking parts of his post to other pages though. They're "further reading", or at best contextual information - the sort of links [we encourage folks to add to their questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to demonstrate that they've done their research first:

> #### Search, and research
>
> ...and keep track of what you find. Even if you don't find a useful answer elsewhere on the site, including links to related questions that haven't helped can help others in understanding how your question is different from the rest.

I occasionally *add these* to people's posts when there's no organic way to insert crosslinks into the text itself... Don't really see the problem.

Comment: I agree with your reasoning for having them at the bottom, but the format Link Text [`<http://raw-url-in-code-block-wrapped-in-link-markdown>`](http://raw-url-in-code-block-wrapped-in-link-markdown) is of no benefit to anyone... if the markdown for it wasn't so complicated I'd assume someone just didn't know how to use regular URL markdown and correct it for them.

Comment: @OGHaza I prefer to avoid in-line numbered footnotes if they can be avoided. The references section is intended to serve as a collection of all external information sources. There are times where I might have to scatter a numbered reference all over the answer to properly attribute the source.

Comment: It's slightly weird, @OGHaza, but I don't find it particularly bothersome. If I'm gonna spend any time worrying about anything, it's gonna be the thousands of posts that don't bother citing anything, in any format.

Comment: Shog, no I must admit I don't find it particularly bothersome either. @Dogbert, if it was me I'd just use the regular title as link style e.g. Further reading: [Links at the end, like in a research paper](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253976/links-at-the-end-like-in-a-research-paper/) at the bottom, but don't worry I won't be editing that into your posts.